# How Can I Pass a Member Function to a Function Pointer?

Tags: c++, methods, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, delayed-execution

```
class Child;
class Parent
{
public:
  void (*funcPointer)();
  void (*funcPointer2)(Parent* _this);
  void (Child::*funcPointer3)();
};

class Child: public Parent
{
public:
  void TestFunc(){

  }
  void Do(){
    Parent p;
    p.funcPointer=TestFunc; // error, '=': cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall Child::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
    p.funcPointer2=TestFunc; // error too, '=': cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall Child::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(Parent *)'
    p.funcPointer3=TestFunc; //this works
    p.funcPointer3=&Child::TestFunc; // this works too.
    p.funcPointer3();    // error, term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
  }
};
```

How can I pass a member function to a function pointer, and then how would I then call that function pointer?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You can find the corrected C++ FAQ link here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr But again I believe it is irrelevant as it is warning against the **passing** of member function pointers, not the using of member function pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. You either pass a pointer to a static method or Parent has to accept also a pointer to the object.

You might want to look at [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html) and [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function.html) for that:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
struct Y
{
    void say(void) { std::cout << "hallo!";}

    boost::function<void()> getFunc() { return boost::bind(&Y::say, this); }
};

struct X
{
    //non-boost:
    void (Y::*func)();
    Y* objectY;
    void callFunc() { (objectY->*func)(); }

    //boost version:
    boost::function<void()> f;

};


X x;
Y y;
x.f = boost::bind(&Y::say, boost::ref(y));
x.f = y.getFunc();
x.f();
x.func = &Y::say;
x.objectY = &y; 
x.callFunc();
```

Comment: also added a non-boost version.

Comment: it's really what i want! i'm coding in visual studio c++ 6 now, i'm not sure it support the boost::bind and boost:function. do you know?

Comment: I added the required includes, so you simply need to get boost and try it out. But it looks like http://www.boostpro.com/download/ does not support VS6.0, but that doesn't mean bind and function can't work there.

Comment: Might I add that MSVS 2010 or GCC 4.4+ adds support for `std::function` and `std::bind` from C++0X, which are a future-proof standard way of doing this kind of thing.

Comment: good point. But that feature definitely will never be available in MSVC6 :-)

Comment: @rubenvb And might I add the all important lambda in C++11. And with C++14 lambdas, you could even capture `this` by value. I've written an answer which will be of absolutely no help on Visual C++ 6.0, but is the de facto answer for modern compilers.

Answer (score 3):

In response to your last edit, to form a pointer-to-member, you have to use `&` and `classkey::`. There's no equivalent to the function name to pointer-to-function implicit conversion for normal functions.

```
// not valid:
p.funcPointer3=TestFunc;

// valid:
p.funcPointer3 = &Child::TestFunc;
```

To access a member through a pointer-to-member you have to use either the `.*` or `->*` operator.

E.g.

```
(this->*p.funcPointer3)();
```

Comment: this really works, I have to tell the compiler which object the member function pointer to work with. thank you!

Comment: @lovespring This was the best answer before C++11 there is really no need to bloat your executables with Boost.

Answer (score 1):

We can actually accomplish all 3 of your `funcPointer*`s in C++11 with the advent of [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [Lambda Functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Let's talk about each one first and discuss what they are doing:

1. `funcPointer` seeks to call a `Child` method *without* taking in a `Child` object, so the `Child` object would have to be saved. The child object could be saved by pointer: `bind(&Child::TestFunc, this)` Or in C++14 it could be saved by value: `[arg = *this]() mutable { arg.TestFunc(); }`
2. `funcPointer2` seeks to call a `Child` method with a `Parent*`. We could do this like: `[](Parent* arg){ static_cast<Child*>(arg)->TestFunc(); }` Of course this wouldn't be any more legal than `(new Parent)->TestFunc()` so we're assuming that the `Parent*` is in reality a `Child*`, if you were willing to make `Parent` a [Polymorphic Type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects) you could verify before calling in your lambda:

```
[](Parent* arg) {
    assert(dynamic_cast<Child*>(arg) != nullptr);

    static_cast<Child*>(arg)->TestFunc();
}
```

3. `funcPointer3` seeks to store a pointer to a `Child` method, and you already had that working. You just needed to use a `Child` object to call it, for example: `(this->*p.funcPointer3)()`. But you must assign `funcPointer3` like this: `funcPointer3 = &Child::TestFunc`, cause if you try to do this: `funcPointer3 = &TestFunc` you will get the error:

> '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

Next, a function pointer or a member function pointer cannot be used to reference a [Closure Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), so we'll need to convert your function pointers to [`function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects. (`funcPointer3` *is* just a member function pointer, so it doesn't need to be converted, but I will convert it to demonstrate that a `function` object *can* contain a member function pointer and it simplifies the call to: `p.funcPointer(this)`):

```
class Parent {
public:
    function<void()> funcPointer;
    function<void(Parent*)> funcPointer2;
    function<void(Child*)> funcPointer3;
};
```

Now that we've adapted `Parent` we can easily assign as demonstrated in **1**, **2**, and **3**:

```
void Child::Do() {
    Parent p;

    p.funcPointer = bind(&Child::TestFunc, this);
    p.funcPointer2 = [](Parent* arg) { static_cast<Child*>(arg)->TestFunc(); };
    p.funcPointer3 = &Child::TestFunc;
    p.funcPointer();
    p.funcPointer2(this);
    p.funcPointer3(this);
}
```

You probably know this and were just testing, but we could have just as easily used the members of the `Parent` that `Child` inherited from as we could create a new `Parent` object in `Child::Do`. I'm going to switch that up and throw the code in an example: http://ideone.com/yD7Rom