# Binding generic callbacks with arguments c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, generics, callback

I have a class called Renderer that holds two callback objects;

```
void (*drawCall)(const sf::Drawable& drawable, const sf::RenderStates& states);
void (*drawPrimCall)(const sf::Vertex* vertices, unsigned int vertexCount,
    sf::PrimitiveType type, const sf::RenderStates& states);
```

I would like to have a public function that binds these callbacks, it's templated and needs a class that has two draw methods each with their valid parameters, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
inline void setRenderer(T* instance)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    drawCall = std::bind(&T::draw, instance, _1, _2);
    drawPrimCall = std::bind(&T::draw, instance, _1, _2, _3, _4);
}
```

However, as you might imagine this does not work. I'm still learning about std::bind and I'm not sure about the use of placeholders, it's understood what I'm trying to do here.

I've tried looking for answers in Google but it has been a bit daunting, thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

Ok, so the answer given by @Holt works, after changing to std::function my callbacks look like this:

```
std::function<void(const sf::Drawable& drawable, const sf::RenderStates& states)> drawCall_fn;
std::function<void(const sf::Vertex* vertices, unsigned int vertexCount,
                   sf::PrimitiveType type, const sf::RenderStates& states)> drawPrimCall_fn;
```

Now for the setRenderer method due to constraints on external libraries I also need to pass a function reference, like so;

```
template<typename T>
inline void setRenderer(T* instance, void(T::*drawCall)(const sf::Drawable&, const sf::RenderStates&))
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    drawCall_fn = std::bind(drawCall, instance, _1, _2);
}
```

Such that when called I can do it like this:

```
renderer.setRenderer<sf::RenderTarget>(&window, &sf::RenderTarget::draw);
```

**Note: I'm only dealing with drawCall_fn for the moment as I can easily expand after.

UPDATE2: Added missing parameters for setRenderer drawCall.

Comment: What are the types of `drawCall` and `drawPrimCall`? `std::function`?

Comment: Looks to me like you are trying to convert a member function pointer to a function pointer which is impossible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296281/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-to-a-function-pointer for example.

Comment: @Holt They are function pointers but I was looking into making them std::function s. I'm trying out your answer atm.

Comment: @Holt Thanks for your answer so far it has helped me, but please have a look at the updated question. Thanks again!

Comment: @Belfer4 Are you sure you have `drawCall = std::bind(drawCall, ...);`? Shouldn't one of the `drawCall` be named differently? I don't really understand what you want to do here...

Comment: @Holt Sorry yes it now should be drawCall_fn, I've updated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want using function pointers because you need to "capture" (either with a capturing lambda or with a `std::bind`) the `instance`. You should use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
std::function<void(const sf::Drawable&, const sf::RenderStates&)> drawCall;
std::function<void(const sf::Vertex*, unsigned int,
    sf::PrimitiveType, const sf::RenderStates&)> drawPrimCall;
```

Then, you can either use lambda or force the overload resolution of `&T::draw` to assign them:

```
drawCall = [instance](const sf::Drawable& drawable, const sf::RenderStates& states) {
    instance->draw(drawable, states);
});

// Or:
drawCall = std::bind((void (T::*)(const sf::Drawable&, const sf::RenderStates&))&T::draw, 
                     instance, _1, _2);
```

---

In both cases, you have to re-specify the list of arguments, but you can use a small helper function to avoid this:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args, typename... BArgs>
void gbind_mem(std::function<R(Args...)> &fn, R(T::*mfn)(Args...), 
               T *instance, BArgs&&... args) {
    fn = std::bind(mfn, instance, std::forward<BArgs>(args)...);
}
```

Then you can easily bind using:

```
gbind_mem(drawCall, &T::draw, instance, _1, _2);
```

You let the compiler do the hard job of deducing the parameters from `drawCall`.

Answer (score 0):

> ...that holds two **callback objects**

There is no such thing as a *"callback object"* in C++. What you're probably looking for are [function pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions) or [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). In the case of function pointers, your syntax is incorrect - you need to add a `*`:

```
void (*drawCall)(const sf::Drawable& drawable, const sf::RenderStates& states = sf::RenderStates::Default);
void (*drawPrimCall)(const sf::Vertex* vertices, unsigned int vertexCount, sf::PrimitiveType type,
                    const sf::RenderStates& states = sf::RenderStates::Default);
```

You will then be able to set them. Example:

```
void (*callback)(int); 
void real_function(int) { }

int main()
{
    callback = &real_function;
}
```

If your "real function" signature does not match the callback's, you should use captureless [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), which are implicitly convertible to *function pointers*, to adapt it:

```
void (*callback)(int); 
void real_function(int, float) { }

int main()
{
    callback = [](int x){ return real_function(x, 5.f); };
}
```

---

**If you provide a minimal example on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) I will be able to give you a more specific answer.**