# "Invalid use of non-static member function" when creating Arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to write an Arduino library to encapsulate management of multi-segment displays driven by multiple HT16K33 driver boards, each of which is capable of managing up to 8 characters.
I have various devices that each need to manage multiple displays of varying sizes. Sometimes the displays are small (e.g. 2 characters) and multiple displays can be managed on a single controller. In other cases the display may be greater than 8 characters, which means I need to daisy chain multiple controllers. It seemed a good idea to abstract the logical concept of a display from its physical implementation, so that regardless of the display size, I could just invoke SetText(), Clear(), Blink() and similar methods, without having to have my Arduino .ino code worry about controller addresses, Wire commands and the like.

I have the need for timer-based activity such as blanking the display after a specified interval or blinking one or more characters, so I've included the arduino-timer.h library which seemed to be appropriate.

However, when I try to build my code, I get the "Invalid use of non-static member function" in the Display library's ClearEvent(void*). Searching SO has shown me that the specific problem is in my attempt to iterate through the collection of Controller objects for the current display - but I can't work out a way to do this. Searching has suggested that I should be considering "functors" but I can't relate examples given to my issue.

Please could someone explain how I can create an appropriate static function?

Edit:
Here's a MRE - although it may raise lots of other questions so I thought I'd leave the original below.

```
//Display.h
#include <arduino-timer.h> //A library with non-blocking timers

class Display {
public:
    Display(Vector<byte> Addresses);
private:
    Vector<Controller> mControllers;
    Timer<2> mTimer; //A timer used for text timeout and flashing
}

///Display.cpp
Display::Display(Vector<byte> Addresses) {

    for (int i = 0; i < Addresses.size(); i++) {
        Controller c = Controller(Addresses[i]);
        mControllers.push_back(c);
    }
}

void Display::Clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mControllers.size(); i++) {
        mControllers[i].Clear(); //<< ERROR will point here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}

//Controller.h
class Controller {
public:
    Controller(byte Address);
    void Clear();
private:
    byte mAddress;
}

///Controller.cpp
Controller::Controller(byte Address) {
    mAddress = Address;
}
void Controller::Clear(){
    //do stuff
}
```

Error Text:

c:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HT16K33Displays\HT16K33Display.cpp: In member function 'void Display::SetText(char*, byte, int)':
c:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HT16K33Displays\HT16K33Display.cpp:215:26: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'boolean Display::ClearEvent(void*)'
mTimer.in(t, ClearEvent); //<<<<<<< Problem here! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
^
In file included from c:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HT16K33Displays\HT16K33Display.cpp:12:0:
c:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HT16K33Displays\HT16K33Display.h:46:10: note: declared here
boolean ClearEvent(void *);
^~~~~~~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1

- note that this is the text from my development code, which contains a call to the 3rd party timer library I mention above, something like this:

  ```
    void Display::SetText(int Timeout){
        unsigned long t = Timeout * 1000;
        mTimer.in(t, ClearEvent);
    }
  ```

Original:
Here's a very cut down version of my code. Apologies if I've left in or omitted relevant private declarations!!:

```
// Problem Illustration .ino

#include <HT16K33Displays.h> //My library

//I/O Pins
const int C1_SELECT_PIN = 3;
const int C2_SELECT_PIN = 4;

//HT16K33 addresses
byte DC_ADDR[] = {0x70}; //2 x 2-character displays
byte DSL_ADDR[] = {0x71}; //Large display, left portion
byte DSR_ADDR[] = {0x72}; //Large display, right portion


//Displays
byte Addresses[] = {DSR_ADDR, DSL_ADDR};
byte Offset = 4;
byte DigitCounts[] = {8, 3};
Display C1Display(DC_ADDR, (byte)0, (byte)2, C1_SELECT_PIN); 
Display C2Display(DC_ADDR, (byte)2, (byte)2, C2_SELECT_PIN);
Display UFCScratchpad(Addresses, (byte)4, 11, 0);


void setup() {
    //...
}

void loop() {
    // Update the display timers
    UFCScratchpad.Tick();
    C1Display.Tick();
    C2Display.Tick();

    //...
}
```

Here are the classes in my HT16K33Displays Library:

```
// Display.h ================================================================================

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Vector.h> //3rd party library to allow me to have collections of controllers per display
#include <arduino-timer.h> //3rd party library to give me non-blocking timer events
#include "HT16K33Controller.h"

class Display {
public:
    //Constructors
    Display();
    Display(Vector<byte> Addresses, byte InitialOffset, int CharacterCount, int SelectPin);

    //Methods
    void Clear();
    void SetText(char Text[], byte Alignment, int Timeount);
    void Tick();

    boolean BlinkEvent(void *);
    boolean ClearEvent(void *);

private:
    Vector<Controller> mControllers;
    Vector<byte> mAddresses; //The bus address of the controllers above
    int mSelectPin;
};



// Display.cpp ===============================================================================

#include "HT16K33Display.h"
#include "HT16K33Controller.h"
#include <Vector.h>
#include <arduino-timer.h>

//Constructors
Display::Display() {}

Display::Display(Vector<byte> Addresses, byte InitialOffset, int CharacterCount, int SelectPin) {

    int controllerCharactersAvailable = 0;
    int charactersRemaining = CharacterCount;
    int controllersRequired = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int o = InitialOffset;

    
    //Check that there are enough controller addresses:
    controllersRequired = ((CharacterCount + InitialOffset) / 8) + 1;
    if (controllersRequired > Addresses.size()) { return; } //"Insufficient controllers" error.

    //Check that the initial offset is within limits:
    if (InitialOffset > 7 || InitialOffset < 0) { return; } //"Offset outside limits" error.


    //Assign characters to controller(s):
    while (charactersRemaining > 0) {
        if (i >= Addresses.size()) {
            return; //This is an "Insufficient controllers" error, that should have been trapped already.
        }
        controllerCharactersAvailable = 8 - o; //The number of characters on the current controller
        if (controllerCharactersAvailable >= charactersRemaining) {
            //All the remaining characters will fit on this controller

            Controller c = Controller(Addresses[i], o, charactersRemaining);
            mControllers.push_back(c);
            mAddresses.push_back(Addresses[i]);
            //charactersUsed += charactersRemaining;
            charactersRemaining = 0;
        }
        else {
            //Won't fit. At least one more controller is required.
            
            Controller c = Controller(Addresses[i], o, 8 - o);
            mControllers.push_back(c);
            mAddresses.push_back(Addresses[i]);
            //charactersUsed += controllerCharactersAvailable;
            charactersRemaining -= controllerCharactersAvailable;
            o = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    mSelectPin = SelectPin;

}

// --- Methods ------


//Blanks the display
void Display::Clear() {

    for (int i = 0; i < mControllers.size(); i++) {
        mControllers[i].Clear();
    }
}


//Sets the text to display
void Display::SetText(char Text[], int Timeout = 0) {

    // <Do stuff displaying the text>
    //...

    if (Timeout > 0) {
        //Convert to milliseconds
        unsigned long t = Timeout * 1000;
        mTimer.in(t, ClearEvent); //<<<<<<<
    }
}


// Triggers the current timer to check for events
void Display::Tick() {
    mTimer.tick();
}


//Handle text blinking
boolean Display::BlinkEvent(void *) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mControllers.size(); i++) {
        mControllers[i].Blink(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
    return false;
}


//Handle text clearing
boolean Display::ClearEvent(void *) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mControllers.size(); i++) {
        mControllers[i].Clear(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
    return true;
}



// Controller.h ================================================================================

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

class Controller {
public:
    Controller();
    Controller(byte Address, byte Offset, byte CharacterCount);

    void Blink();
    void Clear();

private:
    byte mAddress;
    boolean mBlinkState;
    byte mOffset;
};



// Controller.cpp =================================================================================

Controller::Controller() {}

Controller::Controller(byte Address, byte Offset, byte CharacterCount) {
    mAddress = Address;
    mOffset = Offset;
    mCharacterCount = CharacterCount;

    Wire.begin();
    Wire.beginTransmission(mAddress);
    Wire.write(0x21); //Normal mode
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.beginTransmission(mAddress);
    Wire.write(0xE8); //Brightness E0-EF
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.beginTransmission(mAddress);
    Wire.write(0x81);
    Wire.endTransmission(false);

}


// -- Methods ----------------------------------------------------------------
//Toggles the state of the text
void Controller::Blink() {
    
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < mCharacterCount; i++)
    {
        Wire.beginTransmission(mAddress);

        //Select the character.
        Wire.write((i + mOffset) * 2);

        if (mBlinkState) { //Display is populated
            Wire.write(0x0000);
        }
        else { //Display is blank
            Wire.write(mCharacters[i] & 0x00FF);
            Wire.write((mCharacters[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        }

        Wire.endTransmission(false);
    }
    mBlinkState = !mBlinkState;
}


//Blanks the display
void Controller::Clear() {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < mCharacterCount; i++)
    {
        Wire.beginTransmission(mAddress);

        //Select the character
        Wire.write((i + mOffset) * 2);
        Wire.write(0x0000);

        Wire.endTransmission(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: First please try to create a [mre] to show us. With the emphasis on the *minimal* part. Then add comments in the shown code where you get the errors. And also copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log.

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of [How Can I Pass a Member Function to a Function Pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296281/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-to-a-function-pointer) (though it's horribly outdated one, there should be better dupe somewhere), but we can't really tell without [mcve] - what is `mTimer`? Is all the code *really* required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks chaps. Have edited the original to provide an example that will produce the error. mTimer is a (private) member variable referring to an instance of a timer from the included library. Not sure how to get a build log out of the Arduino IDE. Could not make head/tail out of answers in link & struggle to see its relevance; it's at least a couple of stages above my level of skill.

Comment: @ZG862 `mControllers[i]` is a `Controller` object which doesn't have a `Clear` member function. So `mControllers[i].Clear();` doesn't work. Also always post complete error along with your question. OTOH `Display` have a `Clear` member function.

Comment: @user12002570 - apologies; In cutting down my code to make an MRP, I inadvertently removed Controllers::Clear() - which is present in the code in development. I'll edit the question once more.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Display::SetText(int Timeout){
      unsigned long t = Timeout * 1000;
      mTimer.in(t, ClearEvent);
  }
```

Your problem is indeed here.  You are trying to pass a pointer to the ClearEvent function to this `in` function from the timer library.  I don't know what type it expects, but I imagine it wants a pointer to a void function.

Unfortunately, you are passing a member function.  It has the extra parameter `this` attached to it.  If the timer function is expecting a regular function pointer and not a pointer to a member function of this class, then it is not going to take that.  The only way would be to have a static member function, but that brings all sorts of other baggage.  But that's what the compiler is trying to tell you, that if it were a static member then it could use it here.

Here are a couple of other SO answers that might help:
[C++ callback using class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-callback-using-class-member)
[How can I pass a class member function as a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback)

Comment: Thank you @Delta_G; I shall take a look. As you may have guessed, not coming from a C++ background, my head goes all funny when people mention pointers. :)

Comment: Don't think about the pointer.  The problem is that the function wants a regular void function and you're passing it a class member function.  The `in` function doesn't have a way to keep up with which instance of the Display class to call ClearEvent on.

Comment: Thanks again @DeltaG: Given that I (think I) need to pass a class member function (I need to know which Display object my timer should apply to), does this mean that I simply can't use the 3rd party timer library?

Comment: You can still use that library.  But you need to create a regular non-class function that calls `ClearEvent` on the right `Display` and then give that function to the `mTimer.in` method.  The alternative if you only ever want to have one Display object would be to follow a singleton pattern.  Then you could have a static member that calls ClearEvent on the one instance.